# Sonar raises a blocker issue when I do not close ignite Object

Tags: java, sonarqube, ignite

SonarQube analysis is raising a blocker when I do not close the ignite Object. I am using the cache in a Spring Web Application, and trying to access it like this :

```
Ignite ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(igniteConf);
```

If I close the object in `finally`, I would not be able to reuse it again in the application without initialising and populating again, which I do not want (since the cache has the data that I want to use in the application later). Is there a way to avoid or fix the issue ?

Comment: Did you try making Ignite instance a Spring bean?

Comment: @Denis. Sorry, what do you mean by that ? My ignite configuration is part of the spring context xml. What I am trying to do here, is get the instance of the same cache in my Java code and performing some additional operation on it.

Comment: @Denis Ok. I got your question. Yes, the ignite instance is a Spring bean.

Comment: Is this Java code a part of your Spring app? If so, then try autowiring cache instead of getting it from Ignition.

Comment: Thanks @Denis. That helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll replicate an answer from comments here in more details.

To make Sonar happy you can create a Spring bean corresponding to Ignite instance and autowire it in your place of use. It is effectively equivalent to using Ignition, so you can also just ignore the warning.

Usually you don't have to worry about closing Ignite, as it follows "let-it-crash" principle.

Answer (score 0):

Sonar raises an issue here, to warn you, that this instance should most probably be closed somewhere.

If you notified this warning, but you come to the conclusion that you already took all necessary steps, simply close this issue in SonarQube as "won't fix" or choose one of the other options to close this issue.

Comment: I am using Spring application context to initialise the Ignite cache. At this point in the code, I am getting the same instance and performing a task. Does the spring application context close the cache instance (is Yes, I would ignore the warning) or should I explicitly close it?